# Why might AWS Elastic Beanstalk continue serving an old app version?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed an app on Django and configured to deploy it on [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). An earlier version of the app had admin enabled. I have disabled the same in the new app.

Here is the url.py of the app.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
#from django.contrib import admin
#from django.contrib import admin.site.urls
#admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'firstapp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^jd/', include('jd.urls')),
   # url(r'^admin/', include('admin.site.urls')),
)
```

But when I browse the app's URL the app served is still the older version. I ssh-ed into the server and have checked the files. The files are those of the older app. The AWS EB console shows the new app version as deployed to environment. I also downloaded the code from AWS EB panel and the code belongs to the new app.

The URL of Elastic Beanstalk env is:
http://secondapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/

The admin panel can be accessed here:
http://secondapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/
Ideally this url should result in a 404.

The problem is that in the entire AWS EB console I see the new version of app as deployed and serving (I have tried both by pushing code using git aws.push as well as uploading on the aws eb console) however the actual code residing on ec2 server is still the one the older version of app.

> How can I force upload the code? Is there a delay in actual deployment
>   of code (Although it has been over an hour since I deployed the new
>   version and the code is quite small)

Comment: I'm meanwhile getting a 404 status code for http://secondapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/, does this mean your problem is solved already?

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue nowadays, with a twist: the first time we deploy a new version of the app, it gets it right. When the autoscaling kicks in, though, it deploys the previous version to the new machines. No need to say this can be troublesome as it can happen at any time and you're never sure what's deployed (or be there to fix the issue by re-deploying the latest versions on all machines). I wonder if anybody has any idea why this happens or who to write about this.

Comment: This bug still exists. I notice it when doing an UpdateEnvironment call that requires new instances. EB replaces the instances correctly, but then deploys the old version. I've reported it to AWS enterprise support, so hopefully we'll get it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that you are referencing two different files or structures.

Depending on the API you are using, a lot of them have `npm build` features into them.  It is possible you are editing the "raw" code, not building, and then deploying the same built files. If this is the case, you will need to run your build tool: gulp, webpack or grunt, and then deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

If the [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/?nc1=f_m) is showing your new [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) app version as deployed, this should in fact always be the case, everything else would be a critical error on the AWS side and is a bit doubtful accordingly.

From that angle I'd expect you might not be looking at the correct resources one way or the other - for example, could it be that you have accidentally deployed one version to a different region? (Looking at the wrong region probably happens to almost everyone at some point when working with AWS ;)

Of course, you can't have two deployed apps with the identical environment URL, so one would need to be deployed with a different one in fact (maybe Elastic Beanstalk has chosen one automatically, which can happen depending on the deployment scenario) - here are a few things to try:

1. verify that the environment URL of the new one you are seeing is in fact the one you want it to be and not an automatically generated one
2. given this is just a test deployment, I'd simply delete the new one and would expect the old one to still be available at that URL

Both would confirm the suspicion that you are running two environments in fact, finding the other one should be simple at that point.

Good luck!